# perl HTML::HTMLDoc how to include a base64 img

Tags: html, perl, pdf-generation, base64, htmldoc

I am trying to include either a base64 image or a src="getImage.pl?image.jpg" when creating a PDF with HTML::HTMLDoc.  No Luck.

Does anybody have experience with this module and have some wisdom to share?

Thank You,
~D

+-------------------------------------------------+

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use HTML::HTMLDoc;

$html = new HTML::HTMLDoc('mode'=>'file', 'tmpdir'=>'/tmp'); # Start instance

$html->set_page_size('letter'); # set page size
$html->set_bodyfont('Arial');   # set font
$html->set_fontsize(8.0);       # set fontsize
$html->set_permissions('no-copy'); 
$html->set_permissions('no-modify');
$html->set_permissions('no-annotate');

$html->set_html_content(
qq{
<html><body>Hello World...
<br />
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" border="0" alt="Hello Image">
</body></html>});
$html->title();
$html->set_header('.', 't', '.');
$html->set_footer('D', '.', '/');

$pdf = $html->generate_pdf(); # generate document

$http_headers_out{'Content-Type'} = 'application/pdf';

print $pdf->to_string();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like HTML::HTMLDoc will NOT handle img src from base64 data NOR a cgi script.

There was a great response to this question here:
http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1081554